# What can i use instead of 'ctx' in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a command which is named 'mute':

```
@commands.command(description="Mutes the specified user.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(self,ctx, member: discord.Member, time = None, *, reason = None):
     guild = ctx.guild   #The error occurs when this line runs
     
     mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
     ......
     ......
     ......
```

I want to use this method on **on_message** event.I tried this but i recieved an error which is 'Guild' object has no attribute 'guild'.Therefore,we can say that the error occurs because of the argument for 'ctx' parameter is not correct.

```
await self.mute(message.guild,message.author, "1d", reason= "For too many badwords")
```

So what argument should i use for parameter 'ctx' in **mute** method?

-By the way,When i use **mute** command like that : '!dc mute @person1 1d for beeing toxic' it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to make a separate function that mutes the person and then call it both on your command and on your on_message trigger.

I don't know how your function looks, but it should be something like this:

```py
async def mute_user(self, guild: discord.Guild, member: discord.Member, time = None, reason = None):
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
    #the rest of the function

[...]

@commands.command(description="Mutes the specified user.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(self,ctx, member: discord.Member, time = None, *, reason = None):
    await self.mute_user(ctx.guild, member, time, reason)

[...]

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    [...]
    #i'm just assuming you want to mute the author of the message
    await self.mute_user(message.guild, message.author, "1d", "For too many badwords")
```